# `encode_www_form': undefined method `map'

Tags: ruby

when am trying to execute following code

```
require "net/http"
require "uri"

@appArgs = Array.new
@vmip_and_port = "yyyyy"

def post(url, data)
  uri = URI.parse(url)
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
  request.set_form_data(data)
  response = http.request(request)
  return response
end

def click_inapp(id)
  @appArgs.push(id)
  return
end

def finish_inapp()
  data =  @appArgs.join(",")
  res = post("http://" +@vmip_and_port+"/", data)
  return res.body
end
click_inapp("5X7_photo_paper.png")
click_inapp("4X6_photo_paper.png")
finish_inapp()
```

Am getting

```
uri/common.rb:931:in `encode_www_form': undefined method `map' for "5X7_photo_paper.png,4X6_photo_paper.png":String (NoMethodError)
    from /home/ushusadmin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1761:in `set_form_data'
    from app_utilities.rb:11:in `post'
    from app_utilities.rb:23:in `finish_inapp'
    from app_utilities.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

whats wrong with my code.please corect me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`set_form_data` is expecting a `Hash` of field names and values, not an `string`. So try to:

```
require "net/http"
require "uri"

@appArgs = Hash.new
@vmip_and_port = "172.16.2.40:9090"

def post(url, data)
  uri = URI.parse(url)
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
  request.set_form_data(data)
  response = http.request(request)
  return response
end

def click_inapp(field_name, id)
  @appArgs[field_name] = id
end

def finish_inapp()
  res = post("http://" +@vmip_and_port+"/", @appArgs)
  return res.body
end
click_inapp("png1", "5X7_photo_paper.png")
click_inapp("png2", "4X6_photo_paper.png")
finish_inapp()
```

I'm not really sure about the rest of the program, as I don't want to test and attack your server at `172.16.2.40:9090` :-)

Try `ri Net::HTTP` on the console, to have examples.